# git push fails if history changes in remote

Tags: git

I have scripts which run some git commands and try to push changes. Those changes are not conflicting changes, since each one works with a different file.

Now what is happening is that when one script pulls and tries to push. in that brief moment if history changes, it is not able to push.

How to make sure that if push fails? it rebases or just patches the code changes?

I dont want to force push since that will rewrite the history and i will lose changes.

Note: these all are working on the same branch.

Comment: did you try:  "git pull  --rebase " then push ;

every one working on same branch isn't a good idea

Comment: so u think everyone should work on a different branch and then how do i make sure, everyone merges properly back in main? if i can do that, i am happy to do it. I have main permissions to push/force push.

Comment: also even git pull and git push. During this window. someone can makes changes on remote, making the current history invalid.

Comment: i think i need NFS or something to make sure, commands run while taking a lock. i can't think of any other solution.

Comment: The bigger frame challenge here is why do you have scripts making changes to a git repo, and is git definitely the right tool for the job? Should you be looking for a data store that offers exclusive locks and automatic versioning or change tracking? For instance, an SQL database with "on update" triggers to record the changes.

Comment: we use argo cd which use github as a truth source. We have scripts for some use case.

Comment: How much time elapses between the last fetch/pull before the commits are created, and when they are (attempted to be) pushed?

Comment: git pull --rebase=false --no-edit -X ours origin "$BRANCH" followed by a push . this works for me with a retry logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i think i need NFS or something to make sure, commands run while taking a lock

Actually, since Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), [`git push` has a `--atomic` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37533655/6309), which reinforces what was already a [quasi-atomic operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58273280/6309) before.

So as long as the server is set to reject any divergent push (unless `--force` is used), a `git pull --rebase`, as commented, will be enough.

```
# repeat until git push works:
git pull --rebase
git push --force      # which is quasi atomic
```

Note: [`go-git`](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/search?q=pull%20rebase&type=code) does not support rebase, so you might need to wrap that command (`git pull --rebase`) in a `exec.Command` call, using [`go-git/go-git` `plumbing/transport/file/client.go`](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/db2bc57350561c4368a8d32c42476699b48d2a09/plumbing/transport/file/client.go#L38-L41).

---

The [OP Tilak Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5871514/tilak-raj) proposes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989987/git-push-fails-if-history-changes-in-remote/71991112#comment127347784_71991112):

> `retry 5 git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/main && git pull --rebase=false --no-edit -X ours origin "refs/heads/$BRANCH" && git push -u origin "$BRANCH" &> /tmp/gitplan`

Comment: i cant use git more than 2.17

Comment: you mean to say, a git pull --rebase followed by git push will do the trick? . i assume this answer doesn't hold true without atomic?

Comment: @TilakRaj It does, considering git push is quasi atomic already.

Comment: I am using some go routines to push something as well. We had our product designed around github. Thats why we have go routines and scripts doing things.

Comment: go-git doesnt have a git pull rebase supported.

Comment: i was thinking of distributed locking for the same case. But i really like what u mentioned. I will try it. see how it works. On the go git side, i can only use pull.

Comment: # repeat until git push works: could u tell me small snippet for it? i am assuming. Having some sleep at the end, in a loop or something? how do i check if push fails?

Comment: @TilakRaj "repeat until git push works" just means: "if the push is rejected (because somebody else has pushed first), then `git pull --rebase`, test locally, and push again. You repeat that sequence as long as the push is rejected.

Comment: makes sense. i can use this way of doing thing. ```so you might need to wrap that command (git pull --rebase) in a exec.Command call, using go-git/go-git plumbing/transport/file/client.go.```

could u elaborate this more?

Comment: @TilakRaj the idea is to wrap the git pull --rebase command in an exec.Command call, as coded in https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/db2bc57350561c4368a8d32c42476699b48d2a09/plumbing/transport/file/client.go#L38-L41, since go-git does not support directly any rebase operation.

Comment: so if i have my stuff started with worktrees in go, i can directly in bw go to the same branch and run git pull --rebase and it should work right?

Comment: That's the idea, yes.

Comment: great. i am trying out the whole thing, i will let u know if it works out or not :). thanks for pointing out this. Even my seniors also asked me to do the same stuff. I still don't  understand why this would workout? is it because of the quasi atomic operation?

Comment: where can i read more about this quasi-atomic operation ? i cant find good sources.

Comment: @TilakRaj The first two links of the answer are the sources I have on that "atomic" aspect.

Comment: this doesn't work. it stilll shows the same error

Comment: @TilakRaj And with a `git push --force`?

Comment: i cant do force push. that defeats the purpose os the question

Comment: its says history changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244268/discussion-between-vonc-and-tilak-raj).

Comment: git pull --rebase=false --no-edit -X ours origin "$BRANCH" with a git push. This wrapped in a retry logic works fine for now.

Comment: could u update the answer? `retry 5 git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/main && git pull --rebase=false --no-edit -X ours origin "refs/heads/$BRANCH" && git push -u origin "$BRANCH" &> /tmp/gitplan` this is the actual soln.